# How to modify PBR material reflection with ShaderModifiers?

Tags: scenekit, metal

i'am using PBR material with SceneKit and i would like to modify how my model is reflecting environment. From what i learned i have to use shaderModifier, because using SCNProgram removes all "built in" pbr functions.

What is the proper way to do it ?  Which entry point to choose and what property should be in my interest ?

I tried some things but without success - closest to what i need was:

entry point SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface
and shader string:

```
_surface.view = u_inverseModelViewTransform[3].xyz;
```

but it's working only for 180 degrees of my view - i could tweek it to work, but i think its not the right way to do it.

any pointers ?

Comment: More generally, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to have control over how my environment cubemap is reflected on surface of my model - default pbr reflection is looking bad so i want to play with it - for example stretch it on y axis. If you look a this - http://milionoczu.com/rings.jpg - left is rendered with webgl/glsl - right is mine, scenekit pbr, that reflection on cylindrical objects have those ugly distortions that i cant get rid of, so i think my only way is some shader magic.

Comment: To me it looks like an asset issue. The environment texture seems to be of low quality. I'm unable to reproduce the issue in the SceneKit editor with a torus elongated to look like this ring.

Comment: i even tried 8k spherical map - instead of torus, try with SCNCylinder. Still i would love to know how to modify my reflection with metal for learning purpose :)